# Help with closed graph theorem

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, closed-graph

I come across this exercise to use the closed graph theorem, if anyone can give and idea about it, thanks

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of $L^2([0,1])$ that is included on $C([0,1])$(with the supremum norm $\|.\|$)
I have to show that exist a constant $C$ such that 
$$\|f\|\leq C\|f\|_2$$
for all $f\in M$.

Edit:
Thanks for the answer, now i get other part of the problem, I have to prove that

$$\dim(M)\leq C^2.$$

And I have no idea how... So if you guys can help me with that too.

Comment: I've edited in order to address your second question.

Answer (score 2):

The inclusion
$$
(C([0,1]), || \cdot ||_{\infty}) \longrightarrow (L^2([0,1]),|| \cdot ||_2)
$$
is continuous since for all $f \in C([0,1])$

$$|| f ||_2^2 = \int_0^1 f^2 \leq \int_0^1 ||f||_{\infty}^2  = ||f||_{\infty}^2 $$

If you restrict the inclusion to $M$

$$i: (M, || \cdot ||_{\infty}) \longrightarrow (M,|| \cdot ||_2) $$

is continuous and bijective.

Since $M$ is closed, it is a Banach space, hence $i$ is open (by the open mapping theorem), bijective and continuous.
This means that the inverse $i^{-1}$ is continuos as well, i.e. there exists $C>0$ such that for all $f \in M$ holds
$$|| f ||_{\infty} \leq C|| f ||_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Define $\iota\colon (M,\lVert \cdot\rVert_2)\to (C[0,1],\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty)$ by $\iota(f)=f$. We have to show that $\iota$ is continuous.

Since $M$ and $C[0,1]$ endowed with their respective norms are complete, we have to show that if $\lVert f_n-f\rVert_2\to 0$ and $\lVert f_n-g\rVert_\infty=0$ then $f=g$. 
To see this, notice that $f_n\to g$ a.e. and 
$$\int |g-f|=\int\liminf_n|f_n-f|\leqslant \liminf_n\int|f_n-f|=0,$$
hence $f=g$ a.e.

For the dimension problem, assume that $f_1,\dots,f_{N+1}$ are linearly independent elements of $M$. Then using the orthogonalization process we can assume that this is an orthonormal family (for the usual inner product of $L^2$). We thus have for each $(c_1,\dots,c_{N+1})$ in the unit ball of $\mathbf R^n$ and $x\in [0,1]$ that 
$$\left|\sum_{j=1}^{N+1}c_jf_j(x)\right|\leqslant C.$$
Choosing $c_j(x):= f_j(x)/\sqrt{\sum_{l=1}^{N+1}f_l(x)^2}$, we obtain $N+1\leqslant C^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i already solve the problem (with some idea like the one you write) anyway, the bounty goes for you for taking the time to answer my question :D